# Codeigniter in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I don't understand .htaccess yet. I have problem codeigniter application doesn't work in localhost my application is in this folder sturcture

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/dev.application.pl/public_html/
```

My config.php is

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/dev.application.pl/';
```

And in folder `dev.application.php/` i have .htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public_html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev.application.pl/public_html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your hosts file and add
127.0.0.1     dev.application.pl

$config['base_url'] = 'http://dev.application.pl/';

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```